# How to minimize the difference between datasets

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics

How do I go about matching a real-world dataset to a differential equation that describes it? In this case I have a real, tracked set of pendulum angles over time and self-made python script to generate the set using euler method (with the argument being an air resistance constant). How do I find the minimal difference between the two sets (the constant that best matches my real pendulum)? I've thought about taking the difference of best-fit curves, taking the absolute value and minimizing the integral, but I'm not sure if it's a good solution (especially because it seems computationally demanding). If you don't have the time to answer, please just point me to some material - I'm a non-native highschooler and I have a hard time naming similar concepts. Thanks.

Comment: If you include more information about your model I think you may get a better answer. Including the precise differential equation you are using will help. Based on google for 'parameter estimation for differential equations' it sounds like optimization is a usual approach to the parameter estimation problem you're describing : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60726-estimate-differential-equation-parameters , https://docs.juliadiffeq.org/v1.6.0/analysis/parameter_estimation.html

Comment: It's a second order differential equation:
$\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^{2}} + \frac{\mu d\theta }{dt} +{\frac {g}{\ell }}\sin \theta =0$
where
$\mu=$ air resistance.